# Jboss doesn't map my auto-generate entity class with hibernate-tools

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss6.x, hibernate-tools

A strange thing happens when I put my auto-generated entity classes with hibernate-tools 3.2.4-GA into Jboss 6.1.0-Final. My persistence.xml has every class record with the correct entity:

```
<class>package.server.persistence.base.entity.Groups</class>
```

I found the issue in a hibernate-tools bug:
[here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-10570?page=com.atlassian.jirafisheyeplugin%3acrucible-issuepanel)

My entity is generated with a strange new line near the last bracket:

```
/** * Groups generated by hbm2java */
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS"
)
public class Groups  implements java.io.Serializable {
```

if I manually set:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GROUPS")
public class Groups...
```

Everything works fine:

> 2012-01-12 17:52:46,489 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Binding entity from annotated class: package.server
>   .persistence.base.entity.Groups
>   2012-01-12 17:52:46,490 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Bind entity package.server.persistence.base.entity.Groups on table GROUPS

**edit:** if I made tests with jUnit entities are correctly configured, even if they have the "new line" on annotation. Thus, it seems a jboss issue.

Please, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Whitespace (including newlines) inside annotation parameters is entirely valid. Clearly it's "bug" as it's a bit ugly, but it shouldn't break anything. Morevoer, it's not like it's ported over inside the .class files, so it seems like a compiler bug. What are you using to compile?

Comment: this is my env:
`Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_21, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"`

Comment: Can you post your `javap` output for the class (with the newline)? You have to run `javap Groups` where the .class file is.

Comment: no problem: [link](http://nopaste.info/08f26278b1.html)
ps: package was modified due to company rules

Comment: Apparently Java 6's javap doesn't extract annotation info: can you try with Java 7? Or this: http://types.cs.washington.edu/annotation-file-utilities/

Comment: Sorry for delay.. I was not in office those days.. anyway I tried annotation-file-utilities tool unsuccesfully.. it seems it has a bug [link](http://nopaste.info/18c78b877d.html). Later I'll try with Java7 API

Comment: Hi, same problem here: [jdk17](http://nopaste.info/16731f333e.html) even with jdk 1.7

Comment: This was without the manual fix? And if you remove the line by hand it does show the annotation metadata?

Comment: [jdk17_2](http://nopaste.info/c126caaa4b.html) this is with the correct annotation without new line or blank spaces, but I still can't see annotation.
ps: there are some class member change

Answer (score 0):

this is, like you said, a bug in hibernate-tools. i ran into it when using jboss 6 in a previous project of mine as well.

it's currently unresolved and marked as a fix for hibernate 3.3.0beta1 but sadly there's no workaround or solution (at least that i know of) for it so far... guess you'll just have to wait

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I know it, but I would understand if there is a way to get jboss working with this "wrong" annotation.

Comment: there is no error, it just seems that jboss does not see classes as entity.